# Object of type ProductImage is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error `Object of type ProductImage is not JSON serializable`
I am trying to make model in which I can add multiple images using ManytoManyFeild().and I then I want to serialize it so that I can send it to and show on frontend page.

here is my **models**:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length= 100000 ,null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    file_content = models.ManyToManyField("ProductImage", related_name='file_content', blank=True, null=True)

    offer= models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    property_id = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=True, blank=True)
    media = models.FileField(upload_to='pics')
    

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s-image' % (self.property_id.title)
```

and here is my **serializer.py**:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Product, ProductImage

class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = [ 'property_id','media']
       

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file_content = ProductImageSerializer(many=True)

  
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'title','description', 'price','count', 'file_content',
                    'offer']
     
    extra_kwargs = {
        "file_content": {
            "required": False,
        }
    }
```

and here is my **Views.py**:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer
from . models import Product, ProductImage
from rest_framework.response import Response
from . serializer import ProductSerializer

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser


from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes, parser_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


@api_view(['POST','GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser, FormParser])
def ProductViews(request):
   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_content')
        if files:
            request.data.pop('file_content')

            serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                tweet_qs = Product.objects.get(id=serializer.data['id'])
                uploaded_files = []
                for file in files:
                    content = ProductImage.objects.create(media=file)
                    uploaded_files.append(content)

                tweet_qs.file_content.add(*uploaded_files)
                context = serializer.data
                context["file_content"] = [file.id for file in uploaded_files]
                return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                context = serializer.data
                return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        detail = [{"title": detail.title, "id": detail.id, "count": detail.count, "description": detail.description, "price": detail.price, "offer": detail.offer , "details": detail.file_content.all()}
        for detail in Product.objects.all()]
        return Response(detail)
```

I don't what's wrong so I will be very grateful to you if can help. Thanks

**Note**:If you know any other better way to make a Json that can include a list of images, you can also share it(or its link).

Comment: As for your your note, a dirty solution to including images in a JSON would be to read the image data as binary and store that information within your JSON. to read to image in binary you could use `open(file, "rb")` or use `imageio` package.

Comment: Also if you could create a toy example on GitHub, I could help you better

Comment: It will make code complex to handle

Comment: @Daniz da King if you can share this to someone who may know the solution, I would grateful to you. Actually I myself don't have friends in this circle so mostly I am alone.

Comment: I don't know anyone that is specialized in this problem. Even for them, it would be difficult to provide a solution without a working example project

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    property_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=True, blank=True)
    media = models.FileField(upload_to='pics')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s-image' % (self.property_id.title)
   
    def media_url(self):
        return self.media.url
```

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = [ 'property_id','media','media_url']
```

Comment: thank  you very very very very very very much.